# MOSS 2007 - list permission

Tags: sharepoint, list, permissions, sharepoint-2007

I have configured my list so that users can only read and edit items they have created.

I now need to configure this list so that a particular group of users can edit and read all items on this list. I know users with the 'Manage Lists' permission would be able to do this.

My question is can this be configured to be even more granular to apply a permission that works like the  'Manage Lists' permission but only for a particular list, rather than all lists?

Many Thanks,
Nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant you do this:

1. Create a permission set which has manage lists (do not assign any groups to this)
2. Create a group for the list itself - do not assign any permissions to the group
3. Add people to the group
4. navigate to the list
5. add the group to the groups allowed access to the list
6. modify the group permissions on only this list to include the permission set you created in step 1 (which has manage lists permission).